# Timestamp on file name using PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I have a path in a string,

```
C:\temp\mybackup.zip
```

I would like insert a timestamp in that script, for example,

```
C:\temp\mybackup 2009-12-23.zip
```

Is there an easy way to do this in PowerShell?

Answer (score 269, accepted):

You can insert arbitrary PowerShell script code in a double-quoted string by using a subexpression, for example, $() like so:

```
"C:\temp\mybackup $(get-date -f yyyy-MM-dd).zip"
```

And if you are getting the path from somewhere else - already as a string:

```
$dirName  = [io.path]::GetDirectoryName($path)
$filename = [io.path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($path)
$ext      = [io.path]::GetExtension($path)
$newPath  = "$dirName\$filename $(get-date -f yyyy-MM-dd)$ext"
```

And if the path happens to be coming from the output of [Get-ChildItem](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849800.aspx):

```
Get-ChildItem *.zip | Foreach {
  "$($_.DirectoryName)\$($_.BaseName) $(get-date -f yyyy-MM-dd)$($_.extension)"}
```

Comment: Argh. `get-date -f yyyy-MM-dd` made me stop for a moment before realizing that it's *not* the `-f` *operator* but the short form for the `-Format` *parameter*. It looked rather out of place, somehow :-)

Comment: and if I want the time as well?

Comment: @JohnDemetriou see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I use this for timestamped filenames: $timeStr = get-date -f 'yyyy-MM-dd-HHmmss'
Maybe with out seconds deparnting on the situation.  Note that a colon can't be used in a filename.  Can use a dot or dash if you want to separate time components.

Answer (score 26):

Here's some PowerShell code that should work. You can combine most of this into fewer lines, but I wanted to keep it clear and readable.

```
[string]$filePath = "C:\tempFile.zip";

[string]$directory = [System.IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName($filePath);
[string]$strippedFileName = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($filePath);
[string]$extension = [System.IO.Path]::GetExtension($filePath);
[string]$newFileName = $strippedFileName + [DateTime]::Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd-HHmmss") + $extension;
[string]$newFilePath = [System.IO.Path]::Combine($directory, $newFileName);

Move-Item -LiteralPath $filePath -Destination $newFilePath;
```

Comment: Thanks Tom, That was also a great help

Answer (score 25):

I needed to export our security log and wanted the date and time in Coordinated Universal Time. This proved to be a challenge to figure out, but so simple to execute:

```
wevtutil export-log security c:\users\%username%\SECURITYEVENTLOG-%computername%-$(((get-date).ToUniversalTime()).ToString("yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ")).evtx
```

The magic code is just this part:

```
$(((get-date).ToUniversalTime()).ToString("yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ"))
```

Comment: `hh` is 12-hour time, without `tt` it is not useful. Using `HH` will give you 24-hour time. I'd recommend either `hhmmsstt` or `HHmmss`

Comment: @JoshBrown I changed `hh` to `HH` above.  I think that's what most people will want.

Answer (score 7):

Thanks for the above script. One little modification to add in the file ending correctly. Try this ...

```
$filenameFormat = "MyFileName" + " " + (Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd") **+ ".txt"**

Rename-Item -Path "C:\temp\MyFileName.txt" -NewName $filenameFormat
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have the path on a variable ($pathfile) use this concrete line to get the TimeStamped Path:

(extracted from [here](https://powershellexamples.com/home/Article/10/file-management-add-timestamp-to-file-name): https://powershellexamples.com/home/Article/10/file-management-add-timestamp-to-file-name)

```
$pathFile = "C:\ProgramData\MyApp\file.txt"
$pathFileTimestamp = [System.IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName($pathFile) + "\" + `
        [System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($pathFile) + "_" + `
        (get-date -format yyyyMMdd_HHmmss) + ([System.IO.Path]::GetExtension($pathFile))


Write-Host "Path+File: $pathFile"
Write-Host "Path+File with Timestamp: $pathFileTimestamp"
```

Above will return:

```
PS C:\> Path+File: C:\ProgramData\MyApp\file.txt
        Path+File with Timestamp: C:\ProgramData\MyApp\file_20210328_022045.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
$filenameFormat = "mybackup.zip" + " " + (Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd")
Rename-Item -Path "C:\temp\mybackup.zip" -NewName $filenameFormat
```

Comment: perhaps `$filenameFormat = "mybackup $(Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd").zip" `  since that matches the OP format

Comment: This will create `filenameFormat = "mybackup.zip 2009-12-23"`. Not sure is intended or helpful...

Answer (score 0):

Another approach for renaming.

```
Set-Location C:\Folder_containing_zipfiles
Get-ChildItem -File | ForEach-Object {  Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName  
 $_.Name.Replace('.zip',"_$(get-date -Format yyyy_MM_dd_hh_mm_ss).zip") }
```

Answer (score 0):

use variable to rename existing file

```
Get-Content -Path '${{vars.LOG_PATH}}\eventMapper.log'
$filenameFormat = 'eventMapper-' + (Get-Date -Format 'yyyy-mm-dd-hh-mm') + '.log'
Rename-Item -Path '${{vars.LOG_PATH}}\eventMapper.log' -NewName $filenameFormat
```

file created --> eventMapper-2023-23-21-10-23.log

Answer (score -1):

`Date + Filename` - NOT (`Filename + Date`) - otherwise it messes up file extension.

```
$filenameFormat = (Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd") + " " + "mybackup.zip"
Rename-Item -Path "C:\temp\mybackup.zip" -NewName $filenameFormat
```

Comment: This seems very similar to [Robert Blackwell's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48231902/6045800) but will give the wrong output... Your code will create a file as `2009-12-23 mybackup.zip` while the OP asked for `mybackup 2009-12-23.zip` (which is exactly what Robert's answer outputs)