# Give Date Time on Bat File & Dynamic Path

Tags: batch-file, ssis

I Hae Create BAT File

```
@ECHO OFF
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\dtexec.exe" /FILE "D:\New folder (2)\xslttosql\SSIS-BSMS\SSIS-BSMS\SSIS-BSMS\Package6.dtsx" /REP P >> "D:\TRX_Value.log"
exit
```

but i Want to make the Output which `D:\TRX_Value.log`  path Changed Dynamically and give time information on the file name like `D:\TRX_Value-20130307-144650.log` which mean `2012/03/07 14:46:50`

So is it possible? What kind of script should I write?

Comment: Is PowerShell an option? - would be much easier that anything else. What about JavaScript?

Comment: i new to BAT script, how about powershell? it's look like command prompt?

Comment: Check this answer out - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1954203/powershell-timestamp-on-file-name/1954384#1954384

Answer (score 3):

Dealing with dates is somewhat tricky in BAT files.

A simple solution is to use **WMIC LocalTime** command which returns the current date and time in a convenient way to directly parse it with a `FOR` command. Try something similar to this:

```
@ECHO OFF
FOR /F "skip=1 tokens=1-6" %%A IN ('WMIC Path Win32_LocalTime Get Day^,Hour^,Minute^,Month^,Second^,Year /Format:table') DO (
  SET /A DT=%%F*10000+%%D*100+%%A
  SET /A TM=%%B*100+%%C
  SET FDT=%DT%-%TM%
 )
ECHO "c:\progs\dtexec" /FILE "d:\fldr\pack.dtsx" /REP P "d:\logs\tr%FDT%.log"
```

check the result and correct the execution line to fit your reqs

Comment: +1 I love seeing more examples of the flexibility of `wmic`.  It really is the Swiss Army Knife of Windows.

Answer (score 2):

I like PA's suggestion to use WMIC, but there is a much simpler WMIC implementation.

The OS alias has the localDateTime property in almost the exact format you want:

`YYMMDDhhmmss.ffffff-zzz`

where `ffffff` is fractional seconds, and `zzz` is time zone information. Simple substring operations provide the desired date and time format.

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "ts="
for /f "skip=1" %%A in ('wmic os get localDateTime') do if not defined ts set "ts=%%A"
... your exe call ... >>"D:\TRX_Value-%ts:~0,8%-%ts:~8,6%.log"
```

Comment: Neat!  But if you format the output of `wmic` as a list you don't have to make sure `%ts%` is unset or check if not defined.  `for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%I in ('wmic os get localdatetime /format:list') do set "ts=%%I"`  In any case, `wmic os get localdatetime` was an excellent find!

Answer (score 1):

Just because I like a challenge, here's a batch script / JScript hybrid script that'll format your timestamp the way you want.  Save this with a `.bat` extension.

```
@if (@X)==(@Y) @end /* (batch + jscript hybrid script init)

:: *** Batch script *****

@echo off
setlocal
for /f %%I in ('cscript /nologo /e:jscript "%~f0"') do set "ts=%%I"
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\dtexec.exe" /FILE "D:\New folder (2)\xslttosql\SSIS-BSMS\SSIS-BSMS\SSIS-BSMS\Package6.dtsx" /REP P >> "D:\TRX_Value-%ts%.log"
exit /b

:: *** JScript script *****/

var d = new Date();
WScript.echo(d.getFullYear() + /\d{2}$/.exec('0' + (d.getMonth() + 1)) + /\d{2}$/.exec('0' + d.getDate()) + '-'
+ /\d{2}$/.exec('0' + d.getHours()) + /\d{2}$/.exec('0' + d.getMinutes()) + /\d{2}$/.exec('0' + d.getSeconds()));
```

(dbenham is a master at this sort of stuff.)

Answer (score 1):

Echo's the date and time into 2 temp files, then parses them into correct format, and uses them in your command.

```
@ECHO OFF
Set CURRDATE=%TEMP%\CURRDATE.TMP
ECHO %DATE% > %CURRDATE%
Set CURRTIME=%TEMP%\CURRTIME.TMP
ECHO %TIME% > %CURRTIME%

Set PARSEDATEARG="eol=; tokens=1,2,3,4* delims=/, "
Set PARSETIMEARG="eol=; tokens=1,2,3,4,5* delims=:,., "
For /F %PARSEDATEARG% %%i in (%CURRDATE%) Do SET YYYYMMDD=%%k%%j%%i
For /F %PARSETIMEARG% %%i in (%CURRTIME%) Do SET HHMMSS=%%i%%j%%k

"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\dtexec.exe" /FILE "D:\New folder (2)\xslttosql\SSIS-BSMS\SSIS-BSMS\SSIS-BSMS\Package6.dtsx" /REP P >> "D:\TRX_Value-%YYYYMMDD%-%HHMMSS%.log" exit
```

Comment: This assumes the format of `%date%` is MM/DD/YYYY.  Depending on the user's locale, this might not work.

Comment: @rojo It actually assumes DD/MM/YYYY (as I'm in the UK) but good point. Would need to swap the relevant line to `For /F %PARSEDATEARG% %%i in (%CURRDATE%) Do SET YYYYMMDD=%%k%%i%%j` (swapping the i and j variables in the output) I presume.