# PowerShell: Select file with specific name from the folder and rename it by adding the current date

Tags: date, powershell, file-rename

I sincerely apologize if my question seems too easy. I'm completely new to PowerShell and I'm still learning the basics.

I have a folder `E:\LastMonthBackup`

Where SQL Server everyday adds one new file named ProjectBackup.bak

I need a PowerShell script that could rename this newly added file by adding the date when the file was created.

So in essence I want each new file to be named `ProjectBackup_Year_Month_Day.bak`

I don't want the script to touch the files which already have dates in their names. Only this one new ProjectBackup.bak file should be renamed.

Could you please help me to write such script?

I found a related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1954203/powershell-timestamp-on-file-name), but when I tried applying solution from it in my script it didn't work or maybe I just messed up something. I am totally new to PowerShell so any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If its only one file you want to rename to your pattern, you can try this:

```powershell
$fileToRename = "E:\LastMonthBackup\ProjectBackup.bak"
if (Test-Path $fileToRename)
{
    $fileName = [system.io.path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($fileToRename)
    $dateSuffix = get-date -Format 'yyyy_MM_dd'
    $fileExtension = [system.io.path]::GetExtension($fileToRename)
    $newFileName = '{0}_{1}{2}' -f $fileName, $dateSuffix, $fileExtension
    Rename-Item -Path $fileToRename -NewName $newFileName
}
```

If the file `$fileToRename` exisits, the script determines the filename `ProjectBackup`, the date with format `yyyy_MM_dd` and the file extension `.bak` and formats the new string. Finally, it renames the file to the new name.

Comment: I edited my answer. Instead of -Format 'yyyy_mm_dd' you have to use 'yyyy_MM_dd'

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to answer my question. Your script works great!