# How to use a TimeStamp in a file name using PowerShell in a docker container?

Tags: docker, powershell

I have a PowerShell script that receives live log data and writes it into a file which contains a timestamp in the filename. Locally my script is running fine but when I run it in a docker container I get the following error message:

```
Out-File: /app/myscript.ps1:13

Could not find a part of the path
     | '/app/myapp-logs/live-logfile-10/05/2022-14/12.txt'.
```

Here the relevant line of my code:

`cf logs myapp > ".\myapp-logs\live-logfile-$(Get-Date -Format "dd/MM/yyyy-HH/mm").txt"`

I'm using the latest ubuntu base image and the Powershell Version: 7.2.3-1.deb.

Comment: Use something _other than `/`_ as the separator in the datetime format, eg. `$(Get-Date -Format "dd_MM_yyyy-HH_mm")` :)

Comment: Refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1954203/timestamp-on-file-name-using-powershell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you receive is because you're trying to write to a file in a subdirectory underneath `/app/myapp-logs/live-logfile-10/` - and the directory `live-logfile-10` doesn't exist.

Use something that *isn't* a slash in the datetime format used and the problem will go away:

```
cf logs myapp > ".\myapp-logs\live-logfile-$(Get-Date -Format "dd_MM_yyyy-HH_mm").txt"
```

That being said, I'd recommend using a big-endian datetime format - this will make it much easier to sort the log files by date:

```
cf logs myapp > ".\myapp-logs\live-logfile-$(Get-Date -Format "yyyyMMdd-HHmm").txt"
```